# What's the best way of centre cropping images in python?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I've got 20,000 rectangular images that I want to centre-crop so that I can plug them into a machine learning algorithm.

Tensorflow has tf.image.central_crop() but I wanted to check the pictures before TF gets involved. That function takes a tensor and outputs a tensor.

What's the best tool for cropping them in Python?

EDIT: Alternatively, what's the best algorithm for computing centre crops?

Comment: The fastesr, easiest way to crop them is probably using **GNU Parallel** and **ImageMagick** or **vips**.

Comment: Also, you didn’t mention what format your images are, nor what size you want them cropped to, nor how/where you want the output saved/named.

Comment: Mark, I want same format, just centre cropped. They are png.

Comment: Are they all the same pixel dimensions? Are they all landscape or all portrait?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Both.Irritatingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily and fast without writing any code using **ImageMagick**, which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

In the Terminal, crop an image to the central 50x50 pixels like this, by setting the `gravity` to `center` and specifying a zero offset from that position:

```
magick input.png -gravity center -crop 50x50+0+0 result.png
```

If you want to crop to the largest square, you need to use a function to find the lesser of the height and width and use that for each of the 50s:

```
magick input.png -gravity center -crop "%[fx:h<w?h:w]x%[fx:h<w?h:w]+0+0" result.png
```

Start image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Ok, now we want to do 20,000 images, so we use **GNU Parallel**, that would be:

```
parallel magick {} -gravity center -crop ... {} ::: *.png
```

But now we have some new problems. The list of filenames will be too long for ARG_MAX, so we need to feed the filenames in on `stdin` from `find` like this with null-termination:

```
find . -name \*.png -print0 | parallel -0 magick {} -gravity center -crop ... {}
```

We also have a new problem with the special characters in the `-crop` expression, so we need to ask **GNU Parallel** to work out the quoting for us. So the final command becomes:

```
find . -name \*.png -print0 | parallel -0 --quote magick {} -gravity center -crop "%[fx:h<w?h:w]x%[fx:h<w?h:w]+0+0" {}
```

---

That is an extraordinarily powerful command that will rapidly change thousands of images, overwriting the originals, so please test it on a small subset of your images by copying them to somewhere safe first!

You can get a progress bar with:

```
parallel --bar ...
```

And you can do a *"dry-run"* asking **GNU Parallel** to show you what it *would* do without actually doing anything like this:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

---

There are ways of making this even faster and even easier to read - I may add them later when I have more time.

Comment: Thank you. Really. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your project!

Comment: At some point, I'd like to be able to answer questions like you do. :)

Comment: `find` has the feature that it descends into subdirs. If you do not want this, use `printf "%s\0" *.png` (printf is part of bash).

Answer (score 1):

**This is a simple method to crop an image:-**

```
import Image

def crop_image(file_name,new_height,new_width):

    im = Image.open(file_name+".jpg")
    width, height = im.size   

    left = (width - new_width)/2
    top = (height - new_height)/2
    right = (width + new_width)/2
    bottom = (height + new_height)/2

    crop_im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) #Cropping Image 

    crop_im.save(file_name+"_new.jpg")  #Saving Images 

new_width = 256     #Enter the crop image width
new_height = 256    #Enter the crop image height
file_name = ["google"] #Enter File Names

for i in file_name:
    crop_image(i,new_height,new_width)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see cropped image you can use:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("/path_to_image.jpg")

crop_rectangle = (50, 50, 200, 200)
cropped_image = image.crop(crop_rectangle)

cropped_image.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Python Wand with gravity:

Specifying gravity along with width and height keyword arguments allows a simplified cropping alternative.

```
>>> img.size
(300, 300)
>>> img.crop(width=40, height=80, gravity='center')
>>> img.size
(40, 80)
```

See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/guide/resizecrop.html#crop-images